# How does blockmix in scrypt work? What is the meaning of the H function in scrypt?

Tags: algorithm-design, password-hashing, scrypt

I am trying to understand how `scrypt` works. I am referring to the Algorithm section of `scrypt`'s [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt#Algorithm). There I find this `BlockMix` function:

```
Function BlockMix(B):
    (B0, ... , B2r-1) ← B
    X ← B2r−1
    for i = 0 to 2r − 1 do
        X ← H(X ⊕ Bi)
        Yi ← X
    end for
    Output ← (Y0, Y2, ... , Y2r−2, Y1, Y3, ... , Y2r−1)
```

Now, as far as my understanding goes, this means: expand an `r`-bytes block into its single bytes, namely, `B0, ..., B2r-1`. Set `X` to the last byte, and propagate some perturbation by updating `X` with `H(X ⊕ Bi)`. Finally return the output bytes, somehow shuffled (first the even, then the odds).

What I don't understand is the meaning of that `H` function. It's nowhere specified what it is. I guess it is a function that inputs one byte and outputs one byte. Is that a commonly known function? `H` usually stands for hash. Should I just pick any random bijection between the numbers in `[0, 255]`?

Anyone answering my question might as well consider to add this information to the Wikipedia page, to help the next reader.

Comment: In the original paper by Percival (http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt/scrypt.pdf) BlockMix(.) is parameterised by a function H which *is* a hash function (modelled, later, as a random oracle).

Comment: Ok, that helps. So maybe here blockmix is the implementation of an efficient hash function?

Comment: I stand corrected: the function *ROMix*_H(.,.) is the "ideal" sequential memory-hard function (MHF) that comes with a security proof under the assumption that *H* is a random oracle. Since *ROMix_H* does not fare well in practice, [Per] introduced (as you point out) a "custom" hash function (HF) called *BLOCKMix_{H,r}(.)* where *H* is a HF "which is fast while not possessing excess internal parallelism" ([Per] recommends Salsa20/8). But the drawback is that the resulting MHF (SMix_r(B,N):=ROMix_{BLOCKMix_{H,r}}(B,N)) is not provably memory-hard. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'll sum up the comments: according to the original [paper](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt/scrypt.pdf), $H$ is any hash function which, ideally, uses limited parallelism$^1$, with Salsa20/8 being a candidate.

Footnote 1: In order to make the resulting memory-hard function less susceptible to attacks (which make an essential use of parallelism).